# ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'tuple'

Tags: python, scrapy

I keep getting this error.  When I attach the values to the items using this code below.  Note I didn't include the spider class, the start_requests function, or the first parse function but I don't think there is an error there as they all run fine up until this point.

```
from folder.items import fd
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 def parsenestedgame(self, response):
        nested_url = response.url
        nested_html = response.text
        nested_soup = BeautifulSoup(nested_html, "html.parser")

        odds_results = (nested_soup.find_all("button", "_32ge9K w0u0II _2D_dGb"))
        team_results = (nested_soup.find_all("span", "_2I4p8L"))

        sports = ["Basketball", "Hockey",
                  "Major League Baseball",
                  "Tennis", "Boxing / MMA",
                  "American Football"]
        sportsurls = ["url1", "url2",
                      "url3",
                      "url4", "url5",
                      "url6"]
        sportsdict = dict(zip(sportsurls, sports))
        for key in sportsdict:
            if key in nested_url:
                sport = sportsdict[key]
        teams_list = []
        odds_list = []

        for result in odds_results:
            odds_list.append(result.text)

        for team in team_results:
            teams_list.append(team.text)

        if not teams_list:
            print(f"There were no teams found at {nested_url}.")

        else:

            game = f"{teams_list[0]} vs {teams_list[1]}"

            bookie_list = ["bookie1", "bookie2", "bookie3", "bookie4", "bookie5", "bookie6", "bookie7",
                           "bookie8", "bookie10", "bookie11", "bookie12", "bookie13", "bookie14",
                           "bookie15", "bookie16", "bookie17",
                           "bookie18", "bookie19"]
            if len(odds_list) == 18:

                odds_list1 = [odds_list[0], odds_list[1], odds_list[2], odds_list[3], odds_list[4],
                              odds_list[5], odds_list[6],
                              odds_list[7], odds_list[8]]
                odds_list2 = [odds_list[9], odds_list[10], odds_list[11], odds_list[12], odds_list[13],
                              odds_list[14],
                              odds_list[15], odds_list[16], odds_list[17]]

                odds_list1P = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
                odds_list2P = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

                x, y = 0, 0
                for entries1 in odds_list1:
                    if not entries1:
                        odds_list1[x] = 0
                        odds_list1P[x] = 0
                    else:
                        odds_list1[x] = int(entries1)
                        entries1 = float(entries1)
                        if entries1 > 0:
                            odds_list1P[x] = ((entries1 / 100) + 1)
                        if entries1 < 0:
                            odds_list1P[x] = ((100 / abs(entries1)) + 1)
                        # odds_list1P[x] = (abs(int(entries1)))/(abs(int(entries1))+100)
                    x += 1
                for entries2 in odds_list2:
                    if not entries2:
                        odds_list2[y] = 0
                        odds_list2P[y] = 0
                    else:
                        odds_list2[y] = int(entries2)
                        entries2 = float(entries2)
                        if entries2 > 0:
                            odds_list2P[y] = ((entries2 / 100) + 1)
                        if entries2 < 0:
                            odds_list2P[y] = ((100 / abs(entries2)) + 1)
                        # odds_list2P[y] = (abs(int(entries2)))/(abs(int(entries2))+100)
                    y += 1

                # I now have all the lists I need to pass to items
                print(type(game))
                print(type(teams_list[0]))
                print(type(teams_list[1]))
                print(type(odds_list1[0]))
                print(type(odds_list2[0]))
                print(type(odds_list1P[0]))
                print(type(odds_list2P[0]))
                print(type(bookie_list[0]))
                print(type(sport))

                fd = fd()

                fd["game"] = game

                fd["team1"] = teams_list[0]

                fd["team2"] = teams_list[1]

                fd["odds1a"] = odds_list1[0]

                fd["odds2a"] = odds_list2[0]

                fd["odds1d"] = odds_list1P[0]

                fd["odds2d"] = odds_list2P[0]

                fd["bookie"] = b_list[0]

                fd["sport"] = sport

                yield fd
```

Here is my item below.

```
import scrapy


class fd(scrapy.Item):
    game = scrapy.Field()
    team1 = scrapy.Field()
    team2 = scrapy.Field()
    odds1a = scrapy.Field()
    odds2a = scrapy.Field()
    odds1d = scrapy.Field()
    odds2d = scrapy.Field()
    bookie = scrapy.Field()
    sport = scrapy.Field()
```

When I print the type out right before the above line of code you get this.

OUTPUT

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
2020-06-11 16:58:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'tuple' in <GET URL>
```

I don't get it please help!  I will provide more of my code if needed.

Comment: Please add your complete code, it seems that the problem is after the assignation of your item. Thanks!

Comment: Just edited my post and added more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error occurrs when you call your `folder.item` class in your code:

```py
fd = fd()
```

You are naming your variable in the same way as your `folder.item` class, I suggest to rename this variable:

```py
item_data = fd()
```

Of course, this implies that you will have to change also these part of the code:

```
item_data["game"] = game
item_data["team1"] = teams_list[0]
item_data["team2"] = teams_list[1]
.
.
.
item_data["sport"] = sport

yield fd(**item_data)
```

Hopefully, this will point you in the right direction. Also, I am not sure why you are using `beautiful soup` and `scrapy` together, as far as I can see, you could do it just with scrapy, if there is a specific reason I would be glad to know more about it. Please feel free to ask any questions! :D

Comment: I am going to give this a try here a sec when I get a chance thanks for the response!  I am just switching over from just writing scripts to the  scrapy framework and I am really comfortable with Beautiful Soup already vs the built in version with Scrapy.  I literally copied the code to a new scrapy project from a Beautiful Soup script.

Comment: Sure give it a try and let me know how did it go. Yes, I can understand that it happened the same to me with selenium and requests. And know for nearly 90% of the webscrapping projects I do, I use scrapy.

Comment: It's something wrong with the "game" string.  When I manually enter in a string for that variable it works.  I am just not sure what the error is I tried using .format instead of f- strings and it didn't work either.  And when I do `= str(game)` it doesn't work either.

Comment: Actually it seems to be working now using str(variable) I must have forgotten to save the file the first time!

Comment: Can I yield multiple items doing yield item1(), item2(), item3(), etc?

Comment: I am not sure if you can yield multiple items, can you explain more this idea?

Comment: How would I return multiple items from the same parse function?

Comment: I think you will need to declare them in your ```items.py``` script

Comment: They are declared in the items.py

Comment: I just did each yield statement separately and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you! If my answer helped, please consider selecting my answer as the prefered solution